# Jquery :lt(10) doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to hide all elements except .any and .input and also first 10. But first 10 part doesn't work, it only shows 4. What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<ul class="filter option-set" data-filter-group="actor">
<li class="any"><a href="#filter-actor-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">Any</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-sandro" data-filter-value="sandro">Sandro</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-barbara" data-filter-value="barbara">Barbara</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-ku" data-filter-value="ku">Ku</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-cool" data-filter-value="cool">Cool</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-aid" data-filter-value="aid">Aid</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-leo" data-filter-value="leo">Leo</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-john" data-filter-value="john">John</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-kvara" data-filter-value="kvara">Kvara</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-kuku" data-filter-value="kuku">Kuku</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-bubu" data-filter-value="bubu">Bubu</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-actor-fra" data-filter-value="fra">Fra</a></li>
<li class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="Type and hit Enter to search" class="js_search"></li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(".filter li").not(".any, .input, :lt(10)").hide();
```

Comment: Could you add comments showing which elements you *want* to show, and/or which you do *not* want to show?

Comment: @DavidThomas I want to hide all li, and not hide #1-8 and last.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/T5WMe/

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you **don't** want to hide the first 10 `<li>` elements, you should not exclude them with the ":lt(10)" selector. If you **do** want to hide them, then your code already works.

Comment: @Pointy It doesn't work in implementation as it works on jsfiddle. It is buffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not what I thought. Actually code worked fine, it was just that I had several .filter blocks, and lt would select only first 10 of total not of each block. I realized that and asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390220/jquery-lt10-on-multiple-blocks